# Flexslider LI styles randomly applied

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I've got a css issue that I can't get my head around, and could really use some help.

I'm trying to style flexslider on a drupal 7 installation and some but not all of my list styles are being applied to the images, then it seems like the application is random.

In the flex slider on the bottom of this page:http://www.multibrand.visionmix.us/for-her-all

each LI item has a border but each li is also supposed to have a inset shadow applied to it.
Some LIs do but most don't, and I can't figure out why.

I'm using:

Flexslider 7.x-2.0-alpha3

jQuery Update 7.x-2.3+6-dev set to 1.8

Drupal 7.23

Any ideas would be very welcome

Answer (score 0):

I've got it sorted out.
The images in the LIs were too bug and covering over the effect. Once I resized the images everything was fine.